# How to offset every Shape separately using DragGesture?

Tags: swiftui

I have an array of Star() shapes. I'm able to add new shapes to a screen with button taps. If I have just one shape, I can drag this single shape with a gesture. But if I have two or more shapes, I can only simultaneously drag all the shapes, not each shape separately from the others.

**How to drag each shape separately**?

Here's a code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var arrayOfStars: [any Shape] = []
    @State var off = CGSize.zero
    let star = Star()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Button {
                    arrayOfStars.append(star)
                } label: {
                    Text("Add Star").foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
            ForEach(arrayOfStars.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                star
                    .frame(width: 25)
                    .offset(x: -100)
                    .offset(x: 20 + CGFloat(i * 42), y: -100)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .offset(x: off.width, y: off.height)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { val in
                                off = val.translation
                            }
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you think of a star as a view of an offset. To make it possible to add multiple autonomous stars:

- every star needs its own separate state;
- in order for that state to remain under the control of the parent container, I would suggest encapsulating it in an `ObservableObject`;
- the `ObservableObject` are owned by the container but viewed and updated by the individual stars;
- in order for it to be possible to drag a star more than once, you need to record where it was previously dragged to.

Here is an updated version of your code to show it working. Since I didn't have a star shape to hand, I used an image instead.

```swift
class StarOffset: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    @Published private var offset: CGSize
    private var previousOffset: CGSize

    init(id: Int, initialOffset: CGSize) {
        self.id = id
        self.offset = initialOffset
        self.previousOffset = initialOffset
    }

    var currentOffset: CGSize {
        offset
    }

    func updateOffset(translation: CGSize) {
        offset = CGSize(
            width: previousOffset.width + translation.width,
            height: previousOffset.height + translation.height
        )
    }

    func saveOffset() {
        previousOffset = offset
    }
}

struct Star: View {

    @ObservedObject var offset: StarOffset

    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "star.fill")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 25)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .offset(offset.currentOffset)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { val in
                        offset.updateOffset(translation: val.translation)
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        offset.saveOffset()
                    }
            )
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var starOffsets = [StarOffset]()

    private var nextStarOffset: StarOffset {
        let i = starOffsets.count
        return StarOffset(
            id: i,
            initialOffset: CGSize(
                width: CGFloat(i * 42) - 80,
                height: -100
            )
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Button {
                    starOffsets.append(nextStarOffset)
                } label: {
                    Text("Add Star").foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
            ForEach(starOffsets) { offset in
                Star(offset: offset)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main thing that you need to change is to structure your code so that there are different offsets for the different stars. You have only one `off` state variable, so it’s really not possible to move each star in a different direction.

There are many ways you could reorganize your code to achieve per-star offsetting, but the way I’m going to suggest is that you encapsulate each star, along with its own individual `off` state variable, into a separate View, which I will call StarView. Then with minimal other changes, you get something like this:

```
struct StarView: View {
    @State private var off = CGSize()
    
    var body: some View {
        Star()
            .offset(x: off.width, y: off.height)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { val in
                        off = val.translation
                    }
            )
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var arrayOfStars: [StarView] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Button {
                    arrayOfStars.append(StarView())
                } label: {
                    Text("Add Star").foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
  
            ForEach(arrayOfStars.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                arrayOfStars[i]
                    .frame(width: 25)
                    .offset(x: -100)
                    .offset(x: 20 + CGFloat(i * 42), y: -100)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps!

P.S. There are still some issues relating to how you deal with drag gestures (onChanged vs onEnded), but that’s outside the scope of your question. It should be easy for you to figure that out, just by experimenting with a single StarView.

Answer (score 1):

You should associate an offset to each star. You can make a struct like this:

```
struct OffsetShape: Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    let shape: AnyShape
    var offset: CGSize
    let id = UUID()
    
    static func == (lhs: OffsetShape, rhs: OffsetShape) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.offset == rhs.offset
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        hasher.combine(offset.width)
        hasher.combine(offset.height)
    }
}
```

```
@State var arrayOfStars: [OffsetShape] = []
```

```
Button {
    let i = arrayOfStars.count - 1
    arrayOfStars.append(
        OffsetShape(shape: AnyShape(star), offset: .init(width: 20 + CGFloat(i) * 42, height: -100))
    )
} label: {
    Text("Add Star").foregroundColor(.red)
}
```

```
ForEach($arrayOfStars) { shapeAndOffset in
    // get/set shapeAndOffset.shape.wrappedValue 
    // and shapeAndOffset.offset.wrappedValue instead
}
```

Your drag gesture has a problem though. Once you start dragging, the shape snaps back to its initial position. This is because `val.translation` is relative to the drag start location, not relative to the offset of the shape when the dragging started.

To make the dragging look better, you should also track the starting offset. Update the start offset when each drag gesture ends. See also a more complete guide [here](https://sarunw.com/posts/move-view-around-with-drag-gesture-in-swiftui/).

```
struct OffsetShape: Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    let shape: AnyShape
    var draggedOffset: CGSize = .zero
    var startOffset: CGSize
    let id = UUID()
    
    static func == (lhs: OffsetShape, rhs: OffsetShape) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.finalOffset == rhs.finalOffset
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        hasher.combine(finalOffset.width)
        hasher.combine(finalOffset.height)
    }
    
    var finalOffset: CGSize {
        .init(width: startOffset.width + draggedOffset.width, height: startOffset.height + draggedOffset.height)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var arrayOfStars: [OffsetShape] = []
    let star = Star()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Button {
                    let i = arrayOfStars.count - 1
                    arrayOfStars.append(
                        OffsetShape(shape: AnyShape(star), startOffset: .init(width: 20 + CGFloat(i) * 42, height: -100))
                    )
                } label: {
                    Text("Add Star").foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
            ForEach($arrayOfStars) { shapeAndOffset in
                shapeAndOffset.wrappedValue.shape
                    .frame(width: 25)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .offset(x: shapeAndOffset.wrappedValue.finalOffset.width, y: shapeAndOffset.wrappedValue.finalOffset.height)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { val in
                                shapeAndOffset.draggedOffset.wrappedValue = val.translation
                            }
                            .onEnded({ val in
                                shapeAndOffset.startOffset.width.wrappedValue += val.translation.width
                                shapeAndOffset.startOffset.height.wrappedValue += val.translation.height
                                shapeAndOffset.draggedOffset.wrappedValue = .zero
                            })
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```